# Create a DIV next to the cursor position on click

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, jquery-events

What I'm trying to do is, when a user clicks somewhere on a page, a div containing a random image would show up on in the position of a click and it stays there. This must be able to be repeated, showing a different image every time. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

[Here's a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ctKa4/286/).

JS:

```
$(function(){
    var fadeDelay = 1000;
    var fadeDuration = 1000;
    $(document).click(function(e){
        var div = $('<div class="image-wrapper">')
            .css({
                "left": e.pageX + 'px',
                "top": e.pageY + 'px'
            })
            .append($('<img src="" alt="myimage" />'))
            .appendTo(document.body);

        setTimeout(function() {
            div.addClass('fade-out');           
            setTimeout(function() { div.remove(); }, fadeDuration);
        }, fadeDelay);
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
body {
    position: relative;
}

.image-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    opacity: 1;
}

.image-wrapper.fade-out {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

Comment: Thank you as well! Have a Merry Christmas!

Comment: is there a pure javascript equivalent to this? thnx

Comment: Hope you can help me out on this, adding to this code to create a textarea is easy but how do we set the focus to the new element when created using click? The focus is always on the body of the element for some reason.

Comment: Why is the var div in  "var div = Jquery stuff" necessary?
Wouldn't it work without assigning it to a variable?

Comment: @ArtemYevtushenko in that code sample, I have it fade out after 1 second. If you don't want that, then you don't need the variable.

Answer (score 3):

With random images from 1 to 10:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).click(function(e){
    var num = Math.floor((Math.random()*10)+1);
    var img = $('<div>Image '+num+':<img src="image' + num + '.png" /></div>');
    $("#img_container").html(img).offset({ top: e.pageY, left: e.pageX});
  });
})
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/DcuqB/2/)